# declare a vector return-type function and return the vector

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that has a return-type as a vector according to codecadmey c++ course I can set the return type as an int,bool,std::string,std::vector to name some but when I try to declare a function that returns a vector I get lots of errors including.

1 - invalid use of template-name ‘std::vector’
2 - ‘make_arr’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


std::vector make_arr(int num ){
    std::vector<int> arr(num);
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        cout << arr[i];
    }
}





int main(){
    int num=0;
    cin >> num;
    make_arr(num);
    cout << "done\n";
}
```

Comment: std containers are recipes to create a type. You have to supply the ingredients, ie: `std::vector<int>` for a vector  containing ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> make_arr(int num ){
```

This fixes the first issue which is causing the second issue. You have a 3rd issue that you never actually return the vector, which you just need to do by doing

```
return arr;
```

Then you should do something with the returned vector, but that won't cause any compilation issues if not